# Js count nested functions

Tags: javascript, nested-function

I have got something like this below. How can I get info about how many functions are nested in the function `power()`. Is a Regexp going to work?

```
function power(n){
    function power2(){
        function power3(){
            function power4(){
                return n*n;
            }
            return power4();
        }
        return power3();
    }
    return power2();    
}
let number = power(1);
console.log(number)
```

Comment: How do you want to count them - statically? By executing them? Also, *why* do yo need that - are you sure it's not [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: To statically analyse the source code, get a parser that turns this code into an AST, then traverse that to see how deep the deepest function is nested.

Comment: A bit of a hack, but -> `power.toString().match(/return /g).length` will work here.  But for a more robust solution, like mentioned traversing an AST would be better.

Comment: @VLAZ I just want to display amount of nested functions. Im learning JS and this is one of my task to solve.

Comment: How is this a beginner task? It's either way too complex for a beginner to handle or alternatively if it's *only* for this function and it's to be done with beginner tools, then it's completely irrelevant as the static analysis (just parsing the string) that will be done is not something you should ever do.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the function as a string with `power.toString()`

Then count the amount of occurences of the word `function` ( -1 as the outer function is also there)

```
function power(n){
    function power2(){
        function power3(){
            function power4(){
                return n*n;
            }
            return power4();
        }
        return power3();
    }
    return power2();    
}
var str = power.toString();
var count = (str.match(/function/g) || []).length -1;
```

And a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75jxk84q/)

Comment: Bear in mind that this is a very naive solution to this problem

Comment: `const power4 = () => n * n; return power4();` or `const randomString = "hello, this is a function"` will make the count inaccurate.

Comment: @Liam It is, fully aware of that. But if OP just wants to count the nested functions in the example, it does the job.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223142/discussion-on-answer-by-michel-js-count-nested-functions).

Answer (score -1):

```
let nested = 0;
function power(n){
    nested++;
    function power2(){
        nested++;
        function power3(){
            nested++;
            function power4(){
                nested++;
                return n*n;
            }
            return power4();
        }
        return power3();
    }
    return power2();    
}
let number = power(5);
console.log(nested)
// To exclude the main function remove nested++ right under function power(n){
```

Comment: What is the object? If this is a beginner task, should be something easy. And he/she said "I just want to display amount of nested functions."